# How do you close the QGIS Commander in 2.18?

Tags: qgis, command-line

I have opened the Commander tool in Processing.  It is sitting over my map window.

How do I remove the Commander from the display?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the `commander` command line, press the `escape` key